# Когда wsgi сервер запускает django приложение

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

В какой момент сервер запускает django приложение? В мануале сказано, что на каждый http запрос запускается wsgi приложение. Но ведь django приложение стартует до http запроса. Все хуки, чтение конфигов, middleware и тд. То есть сервер запускает вначале некий инит?

Comment: wsgi-сервер в момент получения запроса вызывает специальный объект, который прописывается в конфигурации wsgi-сервера (он обычно называется application). Чтобы этот объект application появился, его нужно сперва как-то создать, и в Django он обычно создаётся в файле `wsgi.py` строчкой `application = get_wsgi_application()` — в этот момент и происходит инициализация Django, до всех запросов. А уже после этого wsgi-сервер при каждом запросе запускает это инициализированное приложение.

Comment: Обязательно приводите, пожалуйста, прямо в вопрос строчку из мануала, которая вас натолкнула задать этот вопрос, ссылку на него тоже.